# Android app closing automatically

Tags: android, activity-finish

I have an android app installed on device (4.2.2).
The device will never go to power save mode.
If i leave the app open for more than 30 minutes, the app closes automatically.
And no exception found in the log.
Is this default android behaviour?
If possible please share  any links about this issue.

Comment: post the relevant code and the stacktrace. What do you mean by app closing automatically. crashes??

Comment: No crash. Just closes the applcation and home screen is displayed.

Comment: Possibly you are consuming too much memory over the time. So Framework will be closing your task to get some memory for essential services.

Comment: override Activity onPause and onDestory and log the info. Probably the actiivity goes to background or destroyed.

Comment: Yes. onPause and onDestroy are executed normally.

Comment: Try overriding `onLowMemory()` in application subclass.

Comment: @user2702700, Have you find any solution for the same? I am facing same error. Let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: @HirenPatel I didn't find any solution for this

Comment: @user2702700, Ok no problem

Answer (score 0):

That is just part of how Android manages memory for activities using the Low Memory Killer, even if as of today devices running Android have vast amounts of memory, the same rules are still applied as when it was designed, and it was designed to run on devices with low memory, if you want to keep it alive without user interaction you might have to either use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), or maybe find a way to simulate user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this behaviour just only 4.x, but under 4.x don't, try in Manifest to turn true largeHeap. You have to turn it on in apllications tag attribute. I hope it will help.